# Using Scanner to read entire line of String in Java

Tags: java, set, java.util.scanner

**I have this code:**

```
Set<String> uniquePairs = new HashSet<String>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int t = sc.nextInt();
sc.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

for(int i=0; i<t ;++i) {
    if(sc.hasNext()) {
        String element = sc.next();
        uniquePairs.add(element);
        System.out.println(uniquePairs.size());
    }
}
```

**Input:**

```
5
john tom
john mary
john tom
mary anna
mary anna
```

**My Output (stdout)**

```
1
2
3
3
4
```

**Expected Output**

```
1
2
2
3
3
```

Why it differs? Is it due to `Scanner$nextLine();`?

However, I get correct output if I perform following changes:

- Remove the line:

  ```
  sc.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
  ```
- Replace the line:

  ```
  String element = sc.next();
  ```

  with:

  ```
  String element = sc.next() + " " + scan.next()j
  ```

Please clarify the same?

Comment: I am getting the expected response when I ran the same program you posted.

Comment: In the "replace the line ... with..." - you meant the opposite order, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code which is giving you the wrong output:

```
    Set<String> uniquePairs = new HashSet<String>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    sc.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    for(int i=0; i<t ;++i) {
      if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String element = sc.nextLine();
        uniquePairs.add(element);
        System.out.println(uniquePairs.size());
      }
```

**Output:**
1
2
3
3
4

---

The issue is once you read the `int` value, `new line character` is left behind and gets read in the loop and produces wrong result. You can read that `new line character` using a `nextLine()` call and ignore it. Then use the `nextLine()` method as per the requirement.

**Here is the code producing the correct result.**

```
    Set<String> uniquePairs = new HashSet<String>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();    // Ignore the next line char.

    for(int i=0; i<t ;++i) {
      if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String element = sc.nextLine();
        uniquePairs.add(element);
        System.out.println(uniquePairs.size());
      }
```

**Output:**
1
2
2
3
3